# How to launch a .app file in apple watch simulator

Tags: xcode

I have a simulator build for apple watch app (.app file) when I try to launch the iOS simulator from xcode 6.3, I am able to install the app in the iPhone simulator but the apple watch view is still showing a black screen. Any idea on how we can see the app in apple watch view(iOS simulator -> Hardware ->External display -> apple watch 38mm)

Comment: Do you use the apple watch extension in xcode?